# Input a text file through command line in java

Tags: java, file, input, command

I am trying to write a program that inputs a text file through the command line and then prints out the number of words in the text file. I've spent around 5 hours on this already. I'm taking an intro class using java.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;

public class WordCounter
{
    private static Scanner input;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        if (0 < args.length) {
        String filename = args[0];
        File file = new File(filename);
        }

    openFile();
    readRecords();
    closeFile();
    }

    public static void openFile()
   {
      try
      {
         input = new Scanner(new File(file)); 
      } 
      catch (IOException ioException)
      {
         System.err.println("Cannot open file.");
         System.exit(1);
      } 
  }

    public static void readRecords()
   {
        int total = 0;
        while (input.hasNext()) // while there is more to read
            {
                total += 1;
            }
        System.out.printf("The total number of word without duplication is: %d", total);
     }

    public static void closeFile()
   {
      if (input != null)
         input.close();
   }    
}
```

Each way I've tried I get a different error and the most consistent one is "cannot find symbol" for the file argument in

```
input = new Scanner(new File(file));
```

I'm also still not entirely sure what the difference between java.io and java.nio is so I have tried using objects from both. I'm sure this is an obvious problem I just can't see it. I've read a lot of similar posts on here and that is where some of my code is from.

I've gotten the program to compile before but then it freezes in command prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.nio` is the New and improved version of `java.io`. You can use either for this task. I tested the following code in the command line and it seems to work fine. The "cannot find symbol" error message is resolved in the `try` block. I think you were confusing the compiler by instantiating a `File` object named `file` twice. As @dammina answered, you do need to add the `input.next();` to the while loop for the Scanner to proceed to the next word.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordCounter {

    private static Scanner input;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if(args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("File name not specified.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try {
            File file = new File(args[0]);
            input = new Scanner(file);
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            System.err.println("Cannot open file.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        int total = 0;
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            total += 1;
            input.next();
        }

        System.out.printf("The total number of words without duplication is: %d", total);

        input.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: I understand. Thank you! I was trying to instantiate the file object twice and I was letting my while loop run forever on the first word in the text file.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost correct. Thing is in the while loop you have specified the terminating condition as follows,

`while (input.hasNext())` // while there is more to read

However as you are just increment the count without moving to the next word the count just increases by always counting the first word. To make it work just add input.next() into the loop to move to next word in each iteration.

```
while (input.hasNext()) // while there is more to read
{
total += 1;
input.next();
}
```

Comment: @presence Will you please upvote this if it helps you  :-)